# jquery not working on index page on newly created mvc project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have added referenced jquery on index page but it's not working. on layout page it's working fine.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <scritp>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Test');

        });
    </scritp>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" class="row">
        <input id="txt1" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="txt2" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="OK" /><span id="sum"></span>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to alert message when page ready.

Comment: `<scritp> ... </scritp>` ... perhaps the issue is just a typo? Also, why jQuery *1.10* with a *"new project"*? 1.10 is 6 years old. Consider the latest, [3.4](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/), instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this statement **"on layout page it's working fine"**, it means you are using templating, that is to say you don't even need the `html`,`head`, `body` tags that you have now because they are already in your layout file.

See what @Tyler Roper suggested in the comments

When you have your Layout page/s and you want to include a script in other pages you need to indicate that the scripts should go to the scripts section of the layout page. The same applies to styles.

This is my suggestion.

In your Layout file add `RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @* head stuffs goes here, you can also add the section sytles here *@
</head>
<body>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) @*This is the part you require in other to add scrips from other pages*@
</body>
</html>
```

Then in you home page add `@section scripts` to indicate where the script tag stays

```
<div id="div1" class="row">
    <input id="txt1" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="txt2" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="OK" /><span id="sum"></span>

</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('Test');

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I added script section in layout page used in view but still not working. It's showing text $(document).ready(function () { alert('Test'); }); when i run a project..

Comment: @Ritesh Patel, Can you show portion of the view where you have the scripts added in your question? it would be very helpful

Comment: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div id="div1" class="row">
    <input id="txt1" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="txt2" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="OK" /><span id="sum"></span>
</div>
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <scritp>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Test');

        });
    </scritp>
}

Comment: did you consider changing the script tag from `</scritp>` to `</script>`?